# Any Options to get a MS Forms Formular into HoloLens 2?

Tags: c#, hololens, microsoft-forms

I want to use MS Form Documents to answer questions in the HoloLens 2.

I tried it with a simple code line in unity to open a browser but it obviously doesn't recognized my account / theres no way for a log in

```
 Application.OpenURL("https://forms.office.com/r/********");
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the link opened in the edge browser outside your app? In general, it provides an Entry link for login first.
So, it should display a login page, and then display the form after acquires a token. Can you provide more information about the issue you encountered? Such as a picture.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT It opens the browser inside the app. But I can't use the data in my code for it cause it's just a browser :)

Comment: Do you mean you can’t pass the login parameters or the user tokens to the browser? When you call the `Application.OpenURL("https://forms.office.com/r/********");` method, your account doesn’t be logged in, and the browser navigates to https://forms.office.com/, right? Or you mean that you want to pass other data, such as the cookie, certificates, etc. to the browser? Could you please clarify more details about your requirement? You can describe your expected behavior and what the actual behavior is.